# Добавление маркеров по интервалу SetInterval()

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

По прохождению 1 секунды нужно добавлять по 1 маркеру в списке (list-style-type: circle;).

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var block = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for(i=0; i < block.length; i++) {
    block[0].classList.add('active');
    i++;
    if(i===6) {
      break;
    }
  };
},1000);
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 250px;
}
  
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li.active {
      list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Первый</li>
  <li>Второй</li>
  <li>Третий</li>
  <li>Четвёртый</li>
  <li>Пятый</li>
  <li>Шестой</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось как-то так:

```js
var block = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var intervalId;
var counter = 0;

intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if (counter == block.length - 1)
     clearInterval(intervalId);

  block[counter].classList.add('active');
  counter++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 250px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.active {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Первый</li>
  <li>Второй</li>
  <li>Третий</li>
  <li>Четвёртый</li>
  <li>Пятый</li>
  <li>Шестой</li>
</ul>
```

То есть записываем идентификатор счетчика в переменную. Когда счетчик не нужен - выключаем его через clearInterval